# How can get access token in identity server event handler(IEventSink)

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I sign in my project with identity server.I want to save user tokens. I use to catch token for IEventSink interface.this interface give token (TokenIssuedSuccessEvent) but this token is only contains last 4 char.How can get full token ?

Windows 10 , .net core 2.2.3 , identiy server 4

```
if (evt is TokenIssuedSuccessEvent tokenIssuedSuccessEvent)
{
    Guid userId = new Guid(tokenIssuedSuccessEvent.SubjectId);
    string accessToken = string.Empty;
    foreach (var token in tokenIssuedSuccessEvent.Tokens)
    {
     accessToken = token.TokenValue;
    }
}

accessToken = token.TokenValue; // accessToken  token result is ****i9wQ
```

Comment: Why do you want to save tokens in your identityserver? Is it refresh tokens you want (https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/)?

Comment: because i want to  user login one and unique session(i know, jwt token is unique but user can be login multiple browser. i dont want multiple logins.).How can make to one user login with one session?

Comment: Then you need to look into persistent login saving the refresh token is Oauth2 and not related to authentication (login).